# Java how to retrieve a browser cookie id?

Tags: java

```
        Headers h = t.getResponseHeaders(); // t - is HttpExchange
        String val = h.getFirst("???"); // what to put here?
        System.out.println("result: " + val);
```

I've tried to use a value like "cookie", but it returned null, how can I retrieve the browser cookie id? to implement manually a session?

Comment: Are you using some framework here? Which one?

Comment: @chrylis, no, just HttpServer, HttpExchange from this package com.sun.net.httpserver

Comment: Why are you using that package? `com.sun` packages aren't intended to be directly used by application code, and there's no point in reinventing all of this handling when Spring MVC or Jersey will handle it for you.